# Haskell cant read this double: ".3". Is this a bug?

Tags: parsing, haskell, double

GHC Haskell seems to require a number in front of a decimal point in order to read a Double. Here's the code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let d1 = read "0.3" :: Double
      d2 = read ".3"  :: Double      
  print d1
  print d2
```

Running this produces:

```
0.3
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Is this a GHC bug or just a major limitation?

(I tried reading ".3" with C, Javascript and MS Excel, and all of these could successfully parse ".3" and understand it as a number.  I think I'm seeing the effects of this issue in other areas of my program, including reading command line arguments with the parseargs package and reading Doubles in html forms with Yesod's MForms.)

Is there a known fix or work-around for this issue?

Comment: This isn't a bug or an issue, Haskell defines floating point numbers to be prefaced with a 0 and no space between the `.` and the digits.  This is to avoid ambiguity with the composition operator.

Comment: An obvious fix is to just prefix "0" to your strings before reading them. `readDouble s = read ('0':s) :: Double`

Comment: bheklilr: I don't understand where the ambiguity could arise in my specific use case. I can see how when parsing Haskell code, it would be important to avoid the ambiguity with the composition operator, but in my case, the read function is just parsing a String that is supposed to represent a Double. I can't think of a case in which ".3" should mean anything other than 0.3

Comment: Mark - Your suggestion should work well.  My problem is that I think the same issue exists in the libraries I use. I will forward your suggestion to the library authors. Thanks.

Comment: @Tad, all of the standard types in Haskell that have Read instances are written to read valid Haskell. If you are using `read` on inputs that aren't parseable as valid Haskell, you should probably using something besides `read`.

Comment: You can use the scientific package to read this format.

Comment: @MarkH I don't think that's a good idea. There's a couple ways it can go wrong -- notably, if the number is negative.

Comment: @iand675, I think your comment is the best answer my question. If you convert your comment to an answer (and perhaps reference Lee's helpful definition of a numeric literal in Haskell) then I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm accepting iand675's answer, but he left it only as a comment so I'm copying it here:

All of the standard types in Haskell that have Read instances are written to read valid Haskell. If you are using read on inputs that aren't parseable as valid Haskell, you should probably be using something besides read.

Lee's answer was helpful because it defined Haskell's numeric literals.

Answer (score 17):

From the Haskell report:

**2.5 Numeric Literals**

> A floating literal must contain digits both before and after the
>   decimal point; this ensures that a decimal point cannot be mistaken
>   for another use of the dot character

So this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: From iand675's answer and from Lee's answer, I now understand that read is designed to parse only strings that are valid Haskell. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Chuck - I've never used Ruby before, but it seems to have a pretty easy way to do what I wanted: ".3".to_f   => 0.3

Comment: @Tad: I meant the rule about floating point numbers in the language is the same — you need a leading 0 for floats in Ruby. `.3` is a syntax error. It's true that `".3".to_f` works, but so does `".3 chickens.".to_f`, because Ruby's `String#to_f` is designed to be generous about what it accepts rather than requiring valid code like Haskell.